# How to create PKCE code and verifier for auth code flow?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, oauth, auth0, okta

Following Okta's auth code flow, [they say I need to create a PKCE code](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/implement-grant-type/authcodepkce/main/#flow-specifics) which contains a code verifier and challenger.

It is not clear how to create the values like their example:

```
{
  "code_verifier":"M25iVXpKU3puUjFaYWg3T1NDTDQtcW1ROUY5YXlwalNoc0hhakxifmZHag",
  "code_challenge":"qjrzSW9gMiUgpUvqgEPE4_-8swvyCtfOVvg55o5S_es"
}
```

I know I can send the code challenge in the auth URL like so:

```
https://${ourOktaDomain}/oauth2/v1/authorize?idp=${idp}&client_id=${clientId}&response_type=code&response_mode=query&scope=openid%20email&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flogin%2Fcallback&state=${randomString}&code_challenge=${codeChallenge}&code_challenge_method=S256
```

But it is not clear what I do with the verifier. It says:

> Your app saves the code_verifier for later

Where do I save it the verifier and how do I create these values?

EDIT: Showing code where I set the code_verifier in localStorage

```
const Login = () => {

  const codeVerifier = useMemo(async () => {
    const s256 = await sha256(codeChallenge)
    const verifier = btoa(s256);

    window.localStorage.setItem(state, verifier);
    
    return verifier;
  }, [])

  if (!codeVerifier) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  const queryParams = encode({
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
    redirect_uri: encodeURI(REDIRECT_URI),
    response_type: 'code',
    response_mode: 'query',
    state,
    nonce,
    code_challenge: codeChallenge,
    code_challenge_method: 'S256',
    scope: 'openid email',
    idp: OKTA_IDP
  });

  const socialLoginURI = `${OKTA_AUTH_URI}?${queryParams}`;

  return (
    <Button 
      component="a"
      href={socialLoginURI}
      aria-label="Login Button"
    >
      Facebook Login
    </Button>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was trying to generate the auth string manually. Doing this skips the step that creates the code_verifier (as @philipp-grigoryev pointed out).

I should have been using the Okta sdk to redirect the user which handles the saving the code_verifier in local storage and when the user is redirected back, it extracts the value from local storage again.

This is how I used the SDK to redirect the user to auth

```
const onSocialLogin = () => {
  oktaAuth.signInWithRedirect({ 
    originalUri: '/welcome',
    clientId: CLIENT_ID,
    redirectUri: encodeURI(REDIRECT_URI),
    responseType: 'code',
    responseMode: 'query',
    state,
    nonce,
    codeChallenge,
    codeChallengeMethod: 'S256',
    scopes: ['openid', 'email'],
    idp: FACEBOOK_APP_ID
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`verifier` is sent during an exchange of the code for a token at a later stage. How you store it, it's up to you. The mechanism of producing the challenge from a verifier is described in https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7636#section-4.2

Comment: Ok so could I do something as follows. create code_verifier and savae to localStorage then create code_challenge from the code_verifier. I then redirect user to auth flow with the URL in my original post. Then when user is redirected back to my app, I get the code_verifier from localStorage?

Comment: That's exactly how it's supposed to work :)

Comment: Ok makes sense. I have added to my original post showing how I am now generating the `code_verifier` and saving it to local storage. I still seem to get the same error when being redirected to my redirect_uri. Could this be because Okta doesn't know where to retrieve the verifier from?

Comment: I am using the `LoginCallback` component from `@okta/okta-react` library which is supposed to be handling extracting the verifier for me I think?

Comment: By default, okta component should take care of handling those codes for you, so you don't need to generate or explicitly send them. Try to re-create the issue with a minimal app and if it doesn't work, you can add the link to the repo, so that people can check.

Comment: Does that mean I should be using the okta sdk to generate the auth string with all those query params? I see there is a method within the sdk for `okta.loginWithRedirect` which seems to work for username / password type auth but is there a similar method for the social logins? I can't seem to find it in the type definitions or docs

Comment: okta.signInWithRedirect is what I meant

Comment: I see that you figured it, it seems :)

Comment: I know this thread is old, but for others browsing--don't use localStorage, use sessionStorage, which is a little better for security.